# Inserting values into a created table with while loop

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm working on a while loop exercise on oracle. I have created a table with two columns.

What I want to do is; inserting values into first column with a sequence of from 1 to 1 million(1,2,3,4,5....1000000).

I've tried

```
DECLARE 
   a int := 0; 
BEGIN 
   WHILE a < 1000000 LOOP 
     a := a + 1; 
   END LOOP; 
END; 

insert into Schema_name.table_name 
(column_1)
values('a')
```

P.S: I'm working on Toad 12.9

Would you like to give a hand to me for this?

Comment: You need to move the insert statement to inside the while loop, and you need to insert the value `a`, not the letter `'a'`

Comment: @TonyAndrews just answered the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert `values(a)`, when you write `'a'` you insert the character `'a'` and not the variable `a`

```
DECLARE 
   a int := 0; 
BEGIN 
   WHILE a < 1000000 LOOP 
     a := a + 1; 
     insert into Schema_name.table_name 
     (column_1)
     values(a);
   END LOOP; 
END;
```